# Why Densest packing of equal spheres in three dimensions is not 88.86?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

I placed four spheres of radius R at vertices of a tetrahedron of edge length 2R .When I calculated density I got 88.86.Actualy I wanted to calculate what is the maximum number of earth that can be placed inside sun but hexagonal close packing does not satisfied me ,it has asymmetricity in 3 dimensions as shown in image.
[hexagonal packing creates squire at sides and triangle at above(see selected spheres)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNyIX.png)

but in 2d hexagonal shape is perfectly symmetric from all directions because it is made by placing  circles (in a pattern so it touches other two circles) around the central circle .Maximum number of circle that can be created in a way so that every circle touches all other circles in 2d is three.[hexagonal close packing in 2d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCNgb.png)

Now in 3d Maximum number of sphere that can be created in a way so that every sphere touches all other spheres is 4(All at 4 vertices of tetrahedron ) .So I started placing sphere around central sphere in a pattern so it touches at least three other sphere and I got a [shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjcpp.png) that symmetric from all directions .And locations of center of all surrounding spheres creates icosahedron this shape also have 12 sphere around central one but it takes slightly less volume then hexagonal close packing And it is same as sphere at vertices of tetrahedron .So then I calculated density of spheres of radius R at vertices of tetrahedron of edge length 2R.

Volume of tetrahedron of edge length 2R will be

$$V = \frac{(2R)^3}{6\sqrt{2}}$$
$$ =\frac{2\sqrt{2}R^3}{3}$$
Now to calculate volume of part of  spheres inside tetrahedron I used icosahedron because it can be created by 20 tetrahedron ,the sphere of radius R that surround icosahedron (having edge size of length R) and passes through all vertices of icosahedron, will divided in 20 equal parts by this 20 tetrahedron or by 20 faces of icosahedron (round part of sphere included)
So Volume of part of one sphere inside tetrahedron will be
$$ \frac{1}{20} \left( \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\right)$$
So Volume of part of all 4 sphere inside tetrahedron will be
$$V1 = \frac{4}{20} \left( \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\right)$$
$$ = \frac{4}{15} \left( \pi R^3\right)$$
So Density will be
$$ = \frac{V1}{V}$$
$$ = \frac{\frac{4}{15} \left( \pi R^3\right)}{\frac{2\sqrt{2}R^3}{3}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{5}$$
$$ ~= .8886$$
So I got density of 88.86 but on internet I found that For equal spheres in three dimensions, the densest packing uses approximately 74% of the volume so is there something I missing in calculation  or something else.

Comment: the Voronoi cell about one sphere is a rhombic dodecahedron

Comment: a concrete method involves placing spheres centered at all integer lattice points $(x,y,z) \; \; $  with $x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod 2  \; \;$     Then the radius of each sphere must be $ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} $

Comment: The Intuition from the plane doesn't carry over: the plane can be tesselated with equilateral triangles, and a hexagon can be decomposed in 6 equilateral triangles. There is no tesselation of 3d space into equilateral tetrahedra. Somewhat related, the icosahedron doesn't decompose into 20 equilateral tetrahedra.  (For example, the radius of the circumscribed sphere of the icosahedron does not agree with the edge length, contrary to what happens for the hexagon)

Comment: Another piece of information: The $3$-dimensional kissing number is $12$ and not $13$ as it would be (at least) by a volume computation from the regular simplex (by the way, this was a historical controversy between Newton and D. Gregory. Newton was right.)

Comment: Beside the fact that the locally efficient packing structures suggested by the regular tetrahedron and the regular icosahedron cannot be extended to the entire space (as pointed out by the comments above), it also seems like you made a mistake in calculating the volume ratio associated with these structures. The fraction of a regular tetrahedron covered by balls centered on its vertices is 77.96% (this is known as the Rogers bound). The fraction of the regular icosahedron covered by balls centered at its vertices and its center is 75.47%.